# How to check the static properties of a class against an interface

Tags: typescript

This constructor function in JavaScript:

```
function C() {
    this.x = 100;
}
C.prototype = {
    constructor: C,
    m() {}
};
C.staticM = function () {};
```

I've converted in TypeScript:

```
class C {
    x: number;

    constructor() {
        this.x = 100;
    }

    m() {}
    static staticM() {}
}
```

I've also added these interfaces for `C()`:

```
interface CConstructor {
    new (): CInstance;
    staticM(): void;
}

interface CPrototype {
    constructor: CConstructor;
    m(): void;
}

interface CInstance extends CPrototype {
    x: number;
}
```

But when I write:

```
class C implements CInstance {...}
```

I get the error message:

```
[ts]
Class 'C' incorrectly implements interface 'CInstance'.
Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
    Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'CConstructor'.
    Property 'staticM' is missing in type 'Function'.
```

How can I check the static properties of a class (`staticM()` in my example) against an interface?

Comment: You should describe with words, what do you actually want to do. There are too many interfaces, and it is hard to understand your intention and the problem. There is also a rule on SO to be specific

Comment: How can I annotate the instance and static properties of a class with interfaces?

Comment: You can only specify properties of instance. This is old issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not allow static properties neither in interfaces, nor in abstract classes, this is old issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600

You should not use static props extensively in Typescript, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a static implementation of an interface. You can have the fact that the class satisfies the interface when you assign the class to a typed variable of the interface :

```
class C {
    x: number;

    constructor() {
        this.x = 100;
    }

    m() {}
    static staticM() {}
}

interface CConstructor {
    new (): CInstance;
    staticM(): void;
}

interface CInstance {
    x: number;
    m(): void;
}

let check: CConstructor = C; //error here if implementation is incorrect
```

Or similarly you can use a function to create the class which will check the implementation conforms to the interface

```
function declareC(cls: CConstructor) {
    return cls;
}


const C = declareC(class {
    x: number;

    constructor() {
        this.x = 100;
    }

    m() { }
    static staticM() { }
});
type C =InstanceType<typeof C>

interface CConstructor {
    new(): CInstance;
    staticM(): void;
}

interface CInstance {
    x: number;
    m(): void;
}
```